# How to correctly initialize multidimentional char array and pass it to function?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, char

I'm writing a program which finds exit from maze. I have a multidimentinal array representing the actual maze.

```
const int size = 12;
    char maze[ size ][ size ] = {
            "############",
            "#...#......#",
            "..#.#.####.#",
            "###.#....#.#",
            "#....###.#..",
            "####.#.#.#.#",
            "#..#.#.#.#.#",
            "##.#.#.#.#.#",
            "#........#.#",
            "######.###.#",
            "#......#...#",
            "############",
        };
```

VS C++ gives me a warning message, saying that size is too small for such array. I guess it's because there must be also '\0' symbol in each line. How do I initialize char array without '\0' symbols? I don't want to initialize `size` with value 13 because it's will be too confused to use this constant for functions (printing array, making move etc.) Is there any way to do it?

Also, how to pass this array to function `void mazeTraverse` using pointer?

```
int main()
{
  mazetraverse(maze)
}

void mazeTraverse(char (*maze)[ size ])
```

Such code doesn't works...

Comment: Reminds me of [Nethack](http://www.nethack.org/)

Comment: The function name is `mazeTraverse`. Why are you trying to call `mazetraverse`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to account for the NULL character at the end of the string:

```
char maze[size][size + 1] = { /*  */ };
```

Alternatively, for more flexibility, you can do:

```
char *maze[size] = { /*  */ };
```

---

I see you're using C++. Is there any reason you're not using `std::string`?

```
std::string maze[size] = { /*  */ };
```

It's a lot more flexible; now you just change the prototype to:

```
void mazeTraverse(std::string maze[]);
```

If you're even more insane, you'll use `std::vector<std::string>`.

---

**EDIT:** I recommend learning a bit about [`std::string`](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/string.html). It works just like a `char*` but you don't have to manually allocate it/etc. For example:

```
std::string mystring = "lol";
mystring = "lololol"; // perfectly legal!

std::cout << mystring[0] << "\n";
// Or: printf("%c\n", mystring[0]);

char* sz[8];
strcpy(sz, mystring[0].c_str());

// And so on...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your example works perfect. I'm not using string in C++ style, because I didn't learned it yet. Right now I'm focused on strings in C style.

Comment: @Alex Edited my answer a bit.

Answer (score 2):

So long as you're using C++, why not just make a simple class?:

```
class Maze {
  public:
    Maze(int width, const std::string& data) 
      :width_(width),
       data_(data.begin(), data.end()) {
    }

    char operator()(int row, int column) const { 
      return data_[width_*row + column]; 
    }

  private:
    int width_;
    std::vector<char> data_;
};
```

You can initialize it easily by taking advantage of the fact that subsequent string literals, like "foo" "bar", are implicitly concatenated into "foobar":

```
Maze my_maze(12, 
             "############"
             "#...#......#"
             "..#.#.####.#"
             "###.#....#.#"
             "#....###.#.."
             "####.#.#.#.#"
             "#..#.#.#.#.#"
             "##.#.#.#.#.#"
             "#........#.#"
             "######.###.#"
             "#......#...#"
             "############");
```

Comment: Notice that there aren't any commas after the quotes (in the "array").

Comment: @lidjam: No I definitely meant operator(). Operator[] only allows one argument; we need two (i.e. row and column).

Comment: @muntoo: Exactly. Just to spell it out for everybody: putting string literals next to each other without commas is equivalent to writing out one giant string. The constructor takes this const char* and implicitly converts it to a std::string, which can then be easily copied to the internal representation: a std::vector<char> with no need for null-termination characters.

Comment: Your example is too hard for me to understand. I'm familiar with basis of classes but something like :width_(width),
       data_(data.begin(), data.end()) and std::string is unknown for me right now.

Comment: @SuperElectric : If you meant `operator()` then the signature should be `char operator()(int row, int column) const`. Your code is missing a key part -- which operator you're defining.

Comment: @ildjam: Whoops; I always make that mistake. Corrected.

Comment: @Alex: The line you refer to is called the initialization list. It's used to initialize member variables. What's going on is this: width_ is being initialized with width. The data_ vector is being initialized using the characters in the data string. "begin()" and "end()" return what are called iterators; think of them as pseudo-pointers that mark the beginning and end of the data string's data. For more on initialization lists, see: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6

Answer (score 1):

"Doesn't works"? The code *does* work. And it works perfectly fine. (Assuming the compiler lets you to use those 13-character string literals to initialize arrays of size 12. This is actually an error in C++, but you said that you are getting a mere warning).

This

```
mazeTraverse(maze);
```

will compile and do exactly what you want it to do (the way I understand it). What exactly doesn't work in your case? "Doesn't work" is not exactly a meaningful description of the problem.

As for getting rid of the warning in the array initialization, if you insist on having the array of exact size, you'll have to initialize it in per-character fashion as in

```
char maze[ size ][ size ] = {
  { '#', '#', '#', ... },
  { ...                },
  // and so on
};
```

If you want to use string literals, then as you noted yourself, you have to declare the inner sub-arrays with bigger size

```
char maze[ size ][ size + 1 ] = {
  "############",
  // and so on
};
```

and change the function declaration accordingly

```
void mazeTraverse(char (*maze)[ size + 1 ])
```

Answer (score 1):

To initialize, I would:

```
char* maze[ size ] = {
        "############",
        "#...#......#",
        "..#.#.####.#",
        "###.#....#.#",
        "#....###.#..",
        "####.#.#.#.#",
        "#..#.#.#.#.#",
        "##.#.#.#.#.#",
        "#........#.#",
        "######.###.#",
        "#......#...#",
        "############",
    };
```

To pass parameters you should be able to use char**. So that would be:

```
void mazeTraverse(char ** param)
```